# breezejs navigation property with include not working

Tags: entity-framework, breeze, hottowel

I have server side code written which is including navigational property for many to many relation ship as shown below.

```
var result = _contextProvider.Context.ResourceProperty.Include("AssociatedStandardResourceProperty.AssociatedLists").Where(t => t.ResourceId == resId);
        //Return matching resource properties
        return result;
```

However, when i am trying to retrieve data from breeze datacontext i am getting query execution error as shown below.

```
var getResourceProperties = function (resourceId, resourcePropertyObservable) {

        var query = EntityQuery.from('GetResourceProperties')
            .withParameters({ resourceId: resourceId })
            .expand("AssociatedStandardResourceProperty.AssociatedLists");

        return manager.executeQuery(query)
            .then(querySucceeded)
            .fail(queryFailed);

        function querySucceeded(data) {
            if (resourcePropertyObservable) {
                resourcePropertyObservable(data.results);
            }
            log('Retrieved listObservable from remote data source',
                data, true);
        }
    };
```

Query is failing and all data is retreived in log message i have written in queryFailed function.

I have also checked by removing expand at client side and also removing include at server side and then including expand at client side.

Please let me know how i can make it work.

Thanks

Comment: I have checked that from server side data are getting populated proper in breeze controller action in result var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have observed that problem was due to many to many mapping between two entities . After removing the relationship we are able to retrieve associatedEntities data

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess here, but if you are performing the *include* on the server, then you don't need the *expand* on the client and vice versa. Your example seems to be doing both. What is the error message that you are getting?

Comment: Here is the error log i am geeting in chrome console

    "Error
    at createError 
    at Object.ajaxImpl.ajax.success 
    at fire 
    at Object.self.fireWith [as resolveWith] /scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js:1148:7)
    at done (/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js:8074:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest.callback (/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js:8598:8)
From previous event:
    at promiseWithCallbacks (breeze.debug.js:11237:31)
        
In browser it id displaying complete JSON data in toastr log . I have checked by removing expand("AssociatedStandardResourceProperty.AssociatedLists") but still i am getting the same result.

Comment: I have observed that problem was due to many to many mapping between two entities . After removing the relationship we are able to retrieve associatedEntities data